# Access 2013 VBA If not date format throw error

Tags: vba, date

I have a form in Access 2013. I have a field on that form labelled ExpDateField. I need the date to be formatted as "ddmmmyyyy", i.e. 22Dec2015. If the date is not formatted as such, I want to throw an error. I have so far tried a million approaches. I have something along the lines of:

```
Private Sub ExpDateField_AfterUpdate()

If Not IsDate("ddmmmyyyy") Then
   MsgBox "Error"
End If

End Sub
```

I have also tried Format(02/15/2015, "ddmmmyyyy") and that throws a type error.

Comment: Why the input date must be in that format?  Just store the date and format as ddmmmyyyy when required.

Comment: I am trying to make a validated system for my company. Therefore, it MUST be in this format.

Answer (score -1):

Try Err.Raise Method:

```
Sub erri()
err.Raise (100)
End Sub
```